# Confusion about Riemann and Lebesgue integral

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probabilty space, $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ a measurable space and $X\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ a random variable. The expected value of $X$ is defined as the Lebesgue integral
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_P(X):=\int_{\Omega}X\,\mathrm{d}P 
\end{align}
and by the change of variables formula it holds
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}X\,\mathrm{d}P=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\mathrm{d}P_{X}
\end{align}
where $P_X:=P\circ X^{-1}$ is the distribution (push forward, image measure, $\ldots$) of $X$ with respect to $P$. 
If $X$ has a probabilty density function $f=\frac{\mathrm{d}P_X}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}$, we can write
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\mathrm{d}P_{X}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\cdot f(x)\;\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)
\end{align}

**Questions:**

1. Is the last integral on the right side a Riemann or Lebesgue integral? We plugged in the formula the density function of a normal distribution and calulated it as a Riemann integral!
2. What is the reason for that we can evaluate the integral as a Riemann integral?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer both questions by saying that this is a property of the Lebesgue integral : if $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is so that $|f|$ is Riemann-integrable, then it is Lebesgue-integrable and its Lebesgue-integral in regards to the $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure is equal to its Riemann-integral. In that case, both integrals can be just called "the integral". In other words :

$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\lambda(x) = \int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx$

Comment: For computation we always use the Riemann integral?

Comment: Seeing that the Lebesgue-integral of a measurable function $f$ is defined as $\underset{n\infty}{lim} \int f_n(x)d\lambda (x)$ where $(f_n)$ is a sequence of simple functions that converges towards $f$, it's much easier to just know that this equals to the Riemann-integral, instead of trying to find a sequence $(f_n)$ and calculating the limit of its integral, so yes, you always use the Riemann integral (I have yet to find a counter-example).

Comment: $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is Lebesgue integrable does not hold in general. Only for compact intervalls.

Comment: What is with $\sin (x)/x$?

Comment: My bad, you're right, the argument I should have used is that $|f|$ is Riemann integrable implies that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: I think i understand your arguments and your answer above, but i'm not totally convinced.

Comment: Well, I don't know what more I can tell you. If you really feel like it, you can prove the theorem I mentionned in my answer. An intuitive way to look at it is that both integrals calculate the same thing, that is, the area under the curve. It's just that the Riemann-integral fails for certain functions that the Lebesgue-integral can handle.